# Mifare Classic Card Emulation

Tags: emulation, nfc, mifare

my task is that when the Android device is in contact with an already existing reader that works on the 14443-3 protocol (Mifare Classic). Give it the value of some blocks. The unique ID is not important to me. Also, I already understood that Android HCE is not my option.

Are there any examples? Or the SDK?

Comment: Not possible, unless you have custom hardware or the existing Reader and emulate a Mifare Classic Tag and then all Android phones might not support the proprietary non NFC standard.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Andrew, is it possible using Mifare4Mobile SDK? As far as I understand, this SDK is not available to regular devs?